# Does the Soul Stone always need a sacrifice?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

The Soul Stone in Vormir became concealed in a shrine, accessible only to those who were willing to sacrifice someone that they loved.

> **Red Skull:** Soul holds a special place among the Infinity Stones.  You might say, it is a certain wisdom.
>   **Thanos:** Tell me what it needs.
>   **Red Skull:** To ensure that whoever possesses it understands its power, the stone demands a sacrifice...In order to take the stone, you must lose that which you love. A soul for a soul.

In the events of *Avengers: Infinity War* we see that Thanos gets the Soul Stone by sacrificing the daughter he loved most.

If someone defeats Thanos, does he/she automatically get the Soul Stone or will they still have to sacrifice someone they loved?

Comment: I believe it really is necessary, just like the power stone can only be held by someone powerful, the MCU didn't really explain it that much. 

In the comics tho it doesn't require sacrifice, Adam Warlock gets the soul stone as a gift for saving a planet and can then use its power, moreover, after being rebirth a few times and using the soul stone, he gets connected to the stone, and no longer needs to be holding it to use its powers. I don't know if Adam Warlock will be in the Avengers 4 but it would make a lot of sense, then we could see if a sacrifice would be needed.

Comment: Hence answer does not even lie in comics, PS: I'm aware comic verse is different from MCU

Comment: Even before Gamora was sacrificed we could see blood on the rocks, which means someone has been sacrificed by somebody earlier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 'Avengers: Endgame', it is made clear that the sacrifice is only required to get the stone out of Vormir. Once it is 'out in the open', so as to speak, it can be possessed by other people like the remaining stones.

Answer (score 5):

### No one knows for sure.

Nobody knows yet if every new owner of the stone has to sacrifice someone he loves to get the stone. It might be revealed in *Avengers: Endgame*. Maybe we will see Tony Stark sacrificing himself for Spider-Man, T'challa's sister or perhaps lover sacrifice herself for him, Star-Lord sacrifice himself for Gamora, Cap for Bucky, and so on. Red Skull could just fool Thanos, couldn't he?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ver Nick, but can't we say based on conversation between redskull and thanos that sacrifice is must? Or is it like sacrifice is needed only to extract it from planet Vormir,

Comment: @ZaidSyedMMd The only thing we can say based on what we've seen is that a sacrifice is required to retrieve the stone from Vormir. Until we see somebody (attempt to) take possession of the soul stone after Thanos, we can't say whether a sacrifice is required then; it may be required, but it may not.

Comment: @Vernick about redskull fooling thanos , You're suggesting he played a joke on him like raccoon does getting all artificial gadgets ? :-D

Comment: @ZaidSyedMMd Yeah, he could just fool Thanos like that.

Comment: To be fair, guy is a Nazi, so....

Answer (score 0):

No need to sacrifice, only for first retrieving if the Stone's in Vormir. After that anybody can use it. Why I'm saying this: Natasha sacrifices for the Stone and Hawkeye bring it to Avengers tower. Then the first user was Dr. Banner. Then Thanos (but didn't use it) and at last Tony ended up by using the gauntlet. We can say it the Soul Stone not alone. But I can say the Soul Stone presents in the different situations.