# Why was this sacrifice sufficient?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*...

> Black Widow kills herself on Vormir to obtain the Soul Stone.

The instructions from Red Skull to receive the Soul Stone are that you must sacrifice that which you love the most.

Hawkeye didn't sacrifice anything.

He actively tried to stop it...and failed. How is this death sufficient?

**edit** - It is not the same as [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96797/does-the-soul-stone-always-need-a-sacrifice) question since I am asking about getting the soul stone out of Vormir, specifically in how they did it in Endgame. Not transferring it once it's been removed from Vormir

Comment: good point! what is someone went there alone and just jumped to their death, who gets the stone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the Soul Stone always need a sacrifice?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96797/does-the-soul-stone-always-need-a-sacrifice)

Comment: @Joachim That seems to be asking a very related but different question

Comment: It also undermines a certain part in Infinity war, where Gomorah tried to do the same thing that Black Widow did, and Thanos stopped her. If Black Widow's action was sufficient, then Thanos didn't need to stop Gomorah.

Comment: I think the sacrifice needs to be made off the cliff for it to count; Clint had already lost that which he loves (his family) and that didn't suffice.  If so, Gamora's suicide would not suffice.

Answer (score 36):

Red Skull's instructions are you must ***lose*** that which you love not sacrifice it and Clint does lose what he loves.

> **Red Skull:** In order to take the stone you must lose that which you love. A soul...For a soul.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

> **Red Skull:** In order to take the stone, you must lose that which you love. An everlasting exchange. A soul, for a soul.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Comment: Red Skull's line right before the one quoted in infinity war... "To ensure that whoever possesses it, understand its power. The stone demands a sacrifice." I think this line even further implies that not only is it a sacrifice but that it has to be significant enough so that its power is "understood".

Comment: @noslenkwah Nat sacrifices herself so there _is_ a sacrifice.

Comment: Because of Infinity War, we're thinking about it from the POV of Thanos and then Clint, but if you look at it from Black Widow's perspective, she's losing the only family she's ever had. The stone demands a payment to be made, but it appears to be flexible on the terms.

Comment: @DougDawson Clint and Nat were like brother and sister. They've been close since we first see them together and Clint trusts Nat enoguh to let her know about his family to the point of the kids calling her auntie and naming their next child after her. I think it's safe to say Clint loved Nat too.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Absolutely. My perception of the OP's question was that Clint didn't chuck Black Widow off the cliff and they weren't tied by blood (or kidnapping?), so there wasn't a sacrifice. My point is that Clint and Nat were fighting to BE the sacrifice. Furthermore, I contend that if you put any other Avenger up on the cliff, I bet it would have still worked because of her love for her "family" and her commitment to the cause.

Comment: So losing his entire family at the beginning of the film _doesn't_ count as 'losing that which you love'? Or if it did, it means he could have taken the soul stone without BW's sacrifice. Unless you have to lose it at that time and place (on Vormir). Are we overthinking movie logic?!

Comment: @Alex His family weren't lost.  *The whole point* of the expedition was to return them!  Hypothetically Red Skull might have bought the "I already paid the price" argument, but if so, his family would fail to return.

Comment: "His family weren't lost" can be further proven by Doctor Strange's ability to see the future in which they win, which would be impossible if he died during the snap (as sorcerers cannot see beyond their death).

Comment: @haykam Sorcerers can see the future beyond their death, just not their own future.  The Ancient One knows a lot about Strange's future despite knowing she will not be around to witness it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Part of the future he saw involved him.

Comment: It’s important to note that Red Skull does *not* specify “that which you love *most*,” just that you love whatever is being sacrificed. It’s not as though the twisted, abusive relationship Thanos had with Gamora was really “love,” either, but his neurotic perspective was good enough for that one, too. Despite appearances, the Soul Stone really wasn’t all that picky. Red Skull might well have been one of the *only* characters in the MCU who *couldn’t* offer that sacrifice.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it is not about losing, it is about sacrificing. If it was only losing, Thanos would have let Gamora kill herself when she stole the knife, but he turned it into bubbles to then drag her and throw her, he has to be the one to kill her, not enough that he loses her.

Comment: @Mocas Presumably falling from the top to the bottom is needed. If it needed to be a sacrifice then Nat's for Clint wouldn't have worked which is the whole premise of the question. _"he has to be the one to kill her"_ Clint ___does not___ kill Nat. The only wording in the films is lose not sacrifice.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot but in infinity war, red skull said "to ensure that whoever posseses it understands it's powers, the stone demands a sacrifice, in order to take the stone you must lose that you love". Neither Nat nor Hawkeye are eligible for the stone, one made the sacrifice and the other lost who presumably "love".

Answer (score 5):

Hawkeye doesn't love her as a mate but he does cherish her very much. To the point of willing to be the one who dies, leaving his wife and children who are supposed to reappear. Can you imagine dying while you have possibility of meeting your family once more?

This is why Natasha's death is enough as a tribute to let Hawkeye have the Soul 
Stone.